# Magento2 CSS applied late

Tags: magento2

[image]

Here We've used LESS and problem is when page load it's shows like above screenshot and CSS applied but after 10-15 Sec.

Currently site is in Production Mode and cache enabled. No any other caching mechanism used.

CSS are loaded in `<head>` tag.

So what should I do to load page properly with design?

Comment: Did you run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: @Nikola : First setup upgrade, content deployed, cache cleaned and cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too experience the same problem, the solution would be
change **client side less compilation** to **server side less compilation**

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Fornt-end developement workflow -> Workflow type -> server side less compilation.
```